# Count how many times a Google Slide presentation has been opened - Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides

I want to measure the interaction with some of my Google Slide presentations. To be precise i want to count how many times a presentation has been opened by somebody.

What i have tried so far:

1. Put simple onOpen(e) trigger in the G-Slide presentation to count each opening instance in a Google Sheet
   -> Result: simple onOpen trigger can't do that. Authorization issue...
2. On the last Slide in the presentation create a single table cell with 0 in it. By simple trigger OnOpen(e) get that cell and that number and increment it by 1.
   -> Result: simple onOpen trigger can't do that. Authorization issue...
3. Tried to implement an installable onOpen trigger for the Slide.
   -> Result: There is no installable onOpen trigger for G-Slide. Only for Sheets, Docs, ...

Is there any way to achieve my goal?
If thats not achievable via AppScript I would also be greatful for alternative solutions.

Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your situation, how about using `PropertiesService`? I thought that when `PropertiesService` is used when the Google Slides file is opened, the count can be saved. the sample script is as follows.

`PropertiesService` can be used with the simple trigger of OnOpen.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Slides and save the script. When you reopen the Google Slides, `onOpen()` is run. By this, the number of counts is increased.

```js
// This function is run when the Google Slides file is opened.
function onOpen() {
  const key = "count";
  const p = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  const c = p.getProperty(key);
  p.setProperty(key, c ? Number(c) + 1 : 1);
}

// When you run this function, you can see the current number of count.
function checkCount() {
  const key = "count";
  const p = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  const c = p.getProperty(key);
  console.log(c);
}

// When you run this function, you can reset the number of count.
function clearCount() {
  const key = "count";
  const p = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  p.deleteProperty(key);
}
```

- In this case, you can check the current number of counts by a script (`checkCount` function), and also you can manually check it by [this method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties#manage_script_properties_manually).

#### Reference:

- [Properties Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties)

Comment: thank you for your quick response! I will test your Code tomorrow an let you know if it worked :)

Comment: sorry for the late response. Just letting you know that it worked great for me! Thank you very much, Tanaike!

Comment: @bisasamii Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.